# show hide specific li at bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

As you ll see at code i use bootstrap and i build a left column using nav nav-pills nav-stacked.This is a ul that contains some li such section1,section2,section3,section4,section5.That i want is to show section1,section2 and section5 and ONLY when i click to section2 expands under this section,section3 and 4 (Show only first second and fith li and when click second li expands third and fourth).I noticed collapse at bootstrap but i want to build with javascript or jquery at my own.Any help will be great guys.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vratsasg/dn3gp776/)

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="leftcol col-md-4">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="icon" aria-hidden="true">
                            <img alt="Notifications" width="24" height="20" src="icon.gif">
                        </span>
                        Section1
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation" class="forclick">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="icon" aria-hidden="true">
                            <img alt="Notifications" width="26" height="20" src="icon2.gif">
                        </span>
                        Section2
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation" class="hiden">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="icon" aria-hidden="true">
                            <img alt="Notifications" width="26" height="20" src="icon3.gif">
                        </span>
                        Section3
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation" class="hiden">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="icon" aria-hidden="true">
                            <img alt="Notifications" width="26" height="20" src="icon4.gif">
                        </span>
                        Section4
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="icon" aria-hidden="true">
                            <img alt="Notifications" width="26" height="20" src="icon5.gif">
                        </span>
                        Section5
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.leftcol{
    width:18%;
}

.nav.nav-pills.nav-stacked .hiden{
    display:none;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$('.nav.navpills.nav-stacked .forclick').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.nav.nav-pills.nav-stacked .hiden').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Generally if you want to hide an element is it better to encapsulates it to the element that you will click it such as :

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li role="presentation">
        <a href="#">
            <span class="icon" aria-hidden="true">
                <img alt="Notifications" width="24" height="20" src="icon.gif">
            </span>
            Section1
        </a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="forclick">
        <a href="#">
            <span class="icon" aria-hidden="true">
                <img alt="Notifications" width="26" height="20" src="icon2.gif">
            </span>
            Section2
        </a>
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
            <li role="presentation" class="hiden">
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="icon" aria-hidden="true">
                        <img alt="Notifications" width="26" height="20" src="icon3.gif">
                    </span>
                    Section3
                </a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation" class="hiden">
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="icon" aria-hidden="true">
                        <img alt="Notifications" width="26" height="20" src="icon4.gif">
                    </span>
                    Section4
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
        <a href="#">
            <span class="icon" aria-hidden="true">
                <img alt="Notifications" width="26" height="20" src="icon5.gif">
            </span>
            Section5
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Maybe this way i am going to build this, its not the appropriate because i am not experienced yet.Any suggestions,corrections,advices for the code above will be great.thanks in advance!

Comment: Please sort out your code formatting, this code is ugglyy! Making reading it and subsequently spotting mistake more difficult.

Comment: The last part is yes, but the first 2 snippets have not changed.

Comment: thanks and sorry for tha fail view

Comment: @Gvra you can use http://jsfiddle.net/ and is more easy to help you

Comment: Formatted the html snippets for you

Comment: you have totally right ....i am new in these stuff so i ll make a fiddle tomorrow thanks for the reply and the guidance

Comment: Do you know that you've misspelt 'hidden' in your CSS?

Comment: if you see at third and fourth li class is hiden so the same at css.The problem is at the javascript i think i cant show them when click the second li

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jQuery code has 2 main issues:

1. In your first selector (the one you are binding your click event to), you have a misspelling. `.nav.navpills.nav-stacked .forclick` should be `.nav.nav-pills.nav-stacked .forclick`.
2. Your `find` jQuery function limits the search to the descendants of your `this` element. You can see that the elements you want to target are siblings. Just the selector will work in this case.

**jQuery**

```
$('.nav.nav-pills.nav-stacked .forclick').click(function() {
    $('.nav.nav-pills.nav-stacked .hiden').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

**Live example**

http://jsfiddle.net/6wazs6xj/